# How to wait on authenticating a user's JWT token until OAuth vars are set (via external call at start time) in Node/Express as API server

Tags: node.js, typescript, express, express-jwt

I inherited a node.js/express project and am stuck on something trivial but annoying -- I suspect having to do with the async nature of Node.js

Summary: Node.js/Express API server utilizes "express-oauth2-jwt-bearer" to validate a JWT token for requests to it as an API server on a route it services.  All works splendidly well if I use locally-set .env vars.  ***But***, if I try to read 2 env vars -- that are needed for OAuth -- from an ***external source*** (in this case AWS's SSM) no matter what I try, those env vars get set ***after*** Node.js compiles the OAuth bit, so OAuth is called with null values vs. the real environment vars.  Here are the files involved:

1. server.ts

```
import https from "node:https";
import app from "./index";
import { loadParameters } from "./utils/loadParameters";
import downloadsRouter from "./routes/downloadsmanifest.routes";
...
const getServer = () => {
...
    (if dev) ... {return https.createServer(options, app);}...
  //trying this here, not sure if right place at all
  app.use("/api/downloadsmanifest", downloadsRouter);
  return app;
}

console.log("Loading parameters...");
loadParameters(env, aws_region, parametersPath).then(function () {
  console.log("Successfully loaded parameters...");
  console.log("*in loadParameters*");
  console.log("1) spot checking kvMap: ", kvMap.getInstance().get("auth0_audience"));
  const server = getServer();
  server.listen(port, () => {
    console.log(`[server]: server is listening on ${port}`);
  });
});
```

2. loadparameters.ts

```
import { SSMClient, GetParametersByPathCommand } from "@aws-sdk/client-ssm";
import kvMap from "./kvMap";
...
export const loadParameters = async (
...
  const command = new GetParametersByPathCommand({...
 const response = await client.send(command);...
kvMap.getInstance().set(trimmedName, param.Value);...
...
```

3. downloadsmanifest.routes.ts

```
import { Router } from "express";
import { checkJWT } from "../middlewares/auth";
...
downloadsRouter.use(checkJWT);

downloadsRouter.get("/", (_req, res, _next) => {
  try {
    res.setHeader("Cache-Control", "no-cache");
    res.send(staticTestJSON);
  } catch (error) {
    console.log("Error in downloadsRouter.get: ", error);
    res.sendStatus(503);
  }
});

export default downloadsRouter;
```

4. index.ts

```
import cors from "cors";
import express, { Express, Request, Response } from "express";
import downloadsRouter from "./routes/downloadsmanifest.routes"; 
...
const app: Express = express();
app.get("/", (req: Request, res: Response) => {
  res.send("Server ready!");
});
// app.use("/api/downloadsmanifest", downloadsRouter); <--I tried it from here too
...
export default app;
```

5. auth.ts

```
import { auth } from "express-oauth2-jwt-bearer";
import kvMap from "../utils/kvMap";
...
//BOOOOOMMMMM this is the bad part, kvMap is empty -- like it didn't get a chance to set!!!!
console.log("2) spot checking kvMap in auth.ts: ", kvMap.getInstance().get("auth0_audience"));

export const checkJWT = auth({
  audience: vkMap....,
  issuerBaseURL: kvMap....,
});
```

When the code above runs, the output looks like this:

```
2) spot checking kvMap in auth.ts:  undefined
Loading parameters...
Successfully loaded parameters...
*in loadParameters*
1) spot checking kvMap:  https://example.com
environment is:  development
[server]: server is listening on 3001
```

And that is the part the drives me crazy -- see how 2) is called ***before*** 1) ???  I need a fix that makes sure that auth.ts is called after the kvMap vars are set.

Thanks!